# how to set custom icons on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, icons

i have the code for google map , in that i get three things toggle view, pin point and get address. see the image of my output.

This is my java alert box code

```
    if(stop - start > 1000){
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Map1.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("pick an Option");
            alert.setMessage("I told to pick an option");
            alert.setButton("place a pinpoint", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint,"what's up","2nd String");
                    CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d, Map1.this);
                    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                    overlayList.add(custom);



                }
            });

            alert.setButton2("get address", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());    
                    try{
                        List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
                        if(address.size() > 0){
                            String display = "";
                            for(int i = 0; i<address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){

                                display +=address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                            }
                            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            t.show();
                        }

                    }catch(IOException e){

                    }
                }
            });

            alert.setButton3("Toggle View", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if(map.isSatellite()){
                        map.setSatellite(false);
                        map.setStreetView(true);
                    }else{ 
                        map.setStreetView(false);
                        map.setSatellite(true);
                    }

                }
            });


            alert.show();
            return true;
        }
```

The result output

[image]

now what i want is, i have to add one more alert button to set the custom image icon(taken from our phone sd card). for that when we press on the button directly behave like browse button to set the image and finally that taken image is to be set on google map. when ever we open the map that image also need to display. please post if you have relevant code.